# We have triangle $\triangle ABC$, with $AD\perp BC$, $\angle ABH=20^o$, $\angle HBC=40^o$ and $\angle HCB=30^o$. Find the value of angle $\angle HAC$

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry, triangles

We have triangle $\triangle ABC$, with $AD\perp BC$, $\angle ABH=20^o$, $\angle HBC=40^o$ and $\angle HCB=30^o$. Find the value of angle $\angle HAC$

[image]

We have that $\angle HAB=30^o$, $\angle BAD=30^o$, $\angle BHD=50^o$, $\angle DHC=60^o$, $\angle AHC=120^o$. After I drew it out accurately, I worked out that the answer is $20^o$. But I can't work out how to show it. Could you please explain to me how to solve this question?

Comment: To answer your question, one must first find (the location of) $\angle x$. Whatever $\angle x$ is, noting similar triangles should be useful.

Comment: Show another set of perpendicular lines. $\quad$ I agree that H is the orthocenter, but it's not immediately obvious to me that the other angles can be easily found consequently. All I get is that those 2 angles sum to 60 (which is independent of the orthocenter), but need to split them up.

Comment: @CalvinLin it is straightforward once you know it is orthocenter. You know $\angle ABH$ and $\angle BAH$

Comment: Extend $CH$. Say it meets $AB$ at $K$. What is $\angle BKC$? You know other two angles in $\triangle BKC$.

Comment: @MathLover brilliant, understood that now thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we discussed in the comments, $H$ is the orthocenter and then simple angle chasing gives $\angle HAC = 40^0$.

---

Alternatively, by Trigonometric form of Ceva's theorem, we have

$ \sin (\angle HBC) \ \sin (\angle HCA) \ \sin (\angle HAB) = \sin (\angle ABH) \ \sin (\angle HCB) \ \sin (\angle HAC)$

$\sin 40^0 \sin (60^0-x) \sin 30^0 = \sin 20^0 \sin 30^0 \sin x \ $ ($\angle HAC = x)$

$\sin 40^0 \sin (60^0-x) = \sin 20^0 \sin x$

$\cos (20^0 - x) - \cos(100^0 - x) = \cos (20^0-x) - \cos (20^0+x)$

$\implies x = 40^0$